# Conditional v-model in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to migrate Vue 2 code to Vue 3.

Below piece of code is not supported in Vue 3

```
v-model:value="initial && initial.FirstName"
```

This code was written in Vue 2. `initial` is object, if object is not null then it assigns `FirstName` value. It now produces an error in Vue 3.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this in Vue 3?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional expression in v-model was not a good practice in Vue 2 and is now more strongly enforced that you do not do this in Vue 3. If you need conditional logic in v-model, separate the logic into a `v-if`.

```html
<div v-if="initial" v-model="initial.FirstName">
```

In this case if initial is undefined it will not render the element which will prevent any runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Use `computed()` to get and set `v-model`'s value conditionally:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
const initial = ref();
const value = computed({get(){
    return initial.value?.firstName;
  },
  set(val){
    initial.value && (initial.value.firstName = val);
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <pre>{{ initial }}</pre>
  <input v-model="value" />
  <button @click="initial = {}">Initiate</button>
</template>
```

You can even initiate your object on setting `firstName`:

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstOwzAQ/JWVL6RSSQ+9lbQVoB7gUBBw9CVKN8XFsS0/QqUo/87aIW2RUHOI7Jkd78zaHbs3Jm8DsgUrXGWF8eDQB7PiSjRGWw8dWKynUOnGBI876KG2uoEbEt1wVWnlPAglvCglLGNtNrkb8baUAQkdxVm3R59NOq6APkuNrBrFeSpe57Wwzm/LBukUgH4a/2QpI3oUZn8ksF4voesnZyV1JGbQc9VHP8VsSEe5aOOxMbL0SDuAwlhcdd0pRN8XswglTigyDu1to3col5yljpzBjOhidnEOmzLvKHUt9vnBaUUDTW45i+GFRPtivKCpcLaA3xyclVLq7+eEeRswhU2aT6y+/sEP7hgxzl4tOrQtWTlxvrQ03YHevG/xSOsTSf6DpOor5Bs6LUP0OJQ9BLUj2xd1ye1TehZC7T/c5uhRuTFUNHq+MhpVwMcr0c925/l8vCrW/wD7+Nxp)

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
const initial = ref();
const value = computed({get(){
    return initial.value?.firstName;
  },
  set(val){
    (initial.value ??= {}).firstName = val;
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <pre>{{ initial }}</pre>
  <input v-model="value" />
</template>
```